# Rails - Manually order array of objects by another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, sorting, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 11 items in an array that have and ID of 1 to 11.

Instead of just showing them in the default order, I want to manually customize the order using another array.

```
@items = Item.all # only 11 items in item table
@item_order = [4,9,8,7,3,2,1,10,11,5,6]

@items.sort_by_id ?
```

Is something like this possible? Currently everything I have tried hasn't worked.

Comment: And [**Rails Active query order by multiple values in specific order?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19173020/479863) and [**Sort list of objects according to an array (Rails)**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41419169/479863) and probably dozens more. Of course, it is easier to find the duplicates when you know what *answer* to search for.

Comment: Appreciate the help. For anyone reading - I would suggest using this method: 

b = [5,3,1] 
Country.where(id: b).index_by(&:id).values_at(*b)

Comment: For any database type, `hash = @items.group_by(&:id); @items = @item_order.map(&hash.method(:[])).flatten`